# how to avoid an Arduino pro micro waking up a pc

Tags: usb, arduino-pro-micro, windows

I have an Arduino Pro Micro only sending data via com port, connected to a PC.
I don't use the USB protocol and I think the Arduino send request with USB and it's the reason why my computer wakes up

I checked the device manager and there is no power management tab for the arduino, so I can't refuse the Arduino to wake the system up.
Also my BIOS don't have any option to wake up on a particular key combination

Comment: This "I don't use the USB protoco" is confusing. The Arduino is connected by USB, correct?  So it uses one of over a dozen USB protocols.  Probably USB/CDC.  Or are you trying to emulate a keyboard with the Arduino.  In that case USB/HID. Clearing this up may make it easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: No I use it as a standard Arduino only using the com port

Comment: The Aduino Pro Micro uses an [Atmel,now Microchip, ATMEGA15U4 processor](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Summary.pdf) with built in USB. As it is built into the processor (other Arduinos have the USB outside the processor) your program can alter it. In normal operation I suspect the port is configured for USB/CDC and presents its self as a COM device to a Win computer. Did you check the COM device associated w/the Arduino for a power management tab? If there is no Arduino COM device, could your program have changed the USB protocol?

Comment: My Arduino appears in the com device as an Arduino Leonardo. And the program I have in is the deej project which I found on GitHub

Comment: Well, I'm confused. I just spent a lot of time looking at a [github project](https://github.com/omriharel/deej) that hasn't been touched in 2 years trying to figure out if the host Win computer needs to run a GO program or not. Then chasing down what looks like an obsolete discord account (which would likely be a better place to have this discussion). In the end, I'm no more enlightened as to what to suggest. I think the Arduino looks like a USB/CDC and I think your computer is unusual in that it turns on when seeing USB/CDC activity.  Or maybe any USB activity. IDK.

Comment: Arduinos with USB modules built in the MCU can announce themselves as compound devices consisting of a COM device, a keyboard and a mouse. At least the Leonardo does this, and I suspect yours, too. You might want to look for such devices with the same VID/PID, and then check your power preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the computer is turning on due to the data received over the USB cable from the DEEJ box and not from simply plugging in the USB cable from the DEEJ box.

Consider, if this project otherwise works, re-writing the Arduino Sketch to not send out any data until after a specific digital GPIO pin goes from 1 to 0. Place a N.O. push button switch to ground on that digital GPIO pin. Remember to program that pin as a GPIO input with a pull up. If this works, not only will the DEEJ box control volumes, but might also be able to turn on the computer.

Comment: Before going to the trouble of re-writing the Sketch and adding a switch you might try to erase the Arduino and confirm that simply plugging on an Arduino does not power up your computer.

Answer (score -1):

I just figured out window wakes up when the deej program is running with the Arduino connected,but when the Arduino is connected without the program running there is no problem.
So trouble is deej

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yes, but the questions sounded like how to not wake-up the PC with such a firmware in the Micro

Comment: No problem in answering your own question @Hadrox1.  But, it sounds like you are finding the cause and not a solution.  It is encouraged here (as in all stackexchange web sites) to make the question better by editing it instead. So: 1) Are you running a Windows program for DEEJ  on your Windows computer? 2) "without the program running" Is this the program on the Arduino or on the Windows computer? 3) What is returned whey you type "powercfg -requests" into a command prompt on your Windows computer after it has been powered up by DEEJ?